# Interpret margins (after reghdfe) across groups with logged dependent variable

Tags: regression, linear-regression, stata, marginal-effects

I want to determine the gender wage gap and use the `reghdfe` command to obtain a linear estimate of this:

`ln_real_wage` is the natural log of real annual wages.
`male` returns 1 for male individuals and zero elsewhere.
`high_skilled_chen` returns 1 for individuals working in a high-skill industry and zero elsewhere.
`age` returns the age of the individual and `full_time` returns 1 when an individual works on a full time basis and zero elsewhere.

`eststo: reghdfe ln_real_income i.male##i.high_skilled_chen age age_2 i.full_time, absorb(i.province) vce(cluster id_numeric)`

This is the output:

[image: Reghdfe output from above code]

Then, I run predictive margins to obtain the difference between men and women dependent on the sector that they work in (high-skill sector or not).

`eststo margin: margins, over(i.male i.high_skilled_chen) post`

[image: Margins output]

How do I obtain the % difference in wages between males and females working in the high-skill sector and the % difference between males and females working in a low-skill sector (using the predictive margins)?

Comment: Please don't post images of text

Answer (score 2):

Your base group are unskilled female workers. You can re-run the regression changing the base group to either skilled male workers or female skilled workers. In my example I set male skilled workers as base category (`b1` changes the base category from 0 to 1):
`i.male##i.high_skilled_chen` -> `ib1.male#ib1.high_skilled_chen`.

The coefficient of `male#high_skilled_chen` in the line `0 1` can be transformed to give you the difference in percent between high-skilled male and female workers. Given the sizes of the coefficients I would not use `100*b` percent but the `(exp(b)-1)*100` percent interpretation (you can read the details e. g. [here](https://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/palmer/beta_in_log-linear_regression.pdf)). You need to replace `b` with the coefficient of `0.male#1.high_skilled_chen`. If e.g. the coefficient is `0.3` then you could say that female skilled workers earn on average 35 % more than skilled male workers.

As a side note, it is a better to use `ppmlhdfe` with untransformed wages instead `reghdfe` of log-wages, because you might have people who do not work and thus have an annual income of zero, which cannot be modeled with log-wages. On a more technical side, if your original model inhibits heteroskedasticity, then the log-level model you use is inconsistent (see e.g. [here](https://personal.lse.ac.uk/tenreyro/jensen08k.pdf)). By specifying `cluster()` you implicitly assume that.

Comment: Thanks so much ```@Maultasche```. Is there a way to obtain the % difference between males and females using the predictive margins? For example, ```(exp(11.531) - exp(11.465)/exp(11.465))*100```?

Comment: I think that working with predictive margins might lead to errors due to Jensen's inequality. It is also explained in this [article](https://www.stata.com/stata-news/news34-2/spotlight/). However, you can still use the predictive margin of `ppmlhdfe` as the model estimated by this function is estimating the same model, but on original scale (Jensen's inequality is then no issue as you are on the correct scale).